Get directive of component from another component
I have the following template:
<sc-list #list drawer-track> </sc-list>

<sc-drawer [drawerTrack]="list"></sc-drawer>

I need to get the host element of sc-list inside sc-drawer component using the drawer-track directive.
I was trying to use Injector or EnvironmentInjector inside sc-drawer component, but I couldn't figure out how to use it, or maybe there is another approach that I don't know.

can you clarify the question a bit? do you mean that by using the directive drawer-track on sc-list, the reference to that sc-list will be passed to sc-drawer component (automatically)?

Please clarify your question, from your code, sc-list and sc-drawer are in the same level, how can sc-list inside sc-drawer?

When you create a directive you can indicate "exportAs"
@Directive(
{
  selector: 'drawer-track',
  exportAs: 'drawerTrack'  //<--this line
})export class DrawerTrackDirective {

}

Now, when use a template reference variable you can indicate that your variable should be this directive
<sc-list #list="drawerTrack" drawer-track> </sc-list>

(It the same, e.g. when you use ngModel and write #name="ngModel")
Now, you can inject in your drawerTrack directive the elementRef (declare as public) or the sc-list (use Optional if your directive is applied not only to a sc-list)
constructor(public elementRef:ElementRef,
            @Optional() public scList:ScListComponent){}

So you can use in .ts in your sc-drawer
console.log(this.drawerTrack.elementRef);
console.log(this.drawerTrack.scList.any-property);
//or execute a function
this.drawerTrack.scList.any-function()

NOTE: when we use ViewChild, we can use, {read:ClassName}, e.g.
@ViewChild('list',{read:DrawerTrackDirective})
                   listAsTrackDirective!:DrawerTrackDirective

And in .html
<sc-drawer [drawerTrack]="listAsTrackDirective"></sc-drawer>


Great, thanks a lot, fixed my issue
